# How does geography affect morphological features of the human body

Tags: human-biology, epigenetics, quantitative-genetics

I've seen many times how a person born in one place, goes to another country for a long time, and then they start looking more like the people there, but I never found out how it works. 
[This report](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2332288?uid=3737496&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21101935763213) claims that second generation Japanese, born in the US are taller and heavier than those living in their native lands (there had been no intermingling of races).

- To what extent do the genetic/environmental factors control human morphology ?
- What factors apart from the diet can bring about such morphological differences ?

Comment: I think this needs to be referenced as an actual phenomenon in order to be answerable.

Comment: I'm searching for any relevant research documents right now, and I only find blog posts of people wondering the same thing, but the answers are only based on guesses.

Comment: @user1306322: added a reference for you.. co-incidentally someone told me about this just few hours ago :)

Comment: I think that particular instance probably reflects dietary changes more than anything else.

Answer (score 4):

Geography does not typically affect the morphology of the human body.

In certain special cases, there are physiological adaptations, the most obvious being tanning and [acclimatization to high altitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_high_altitude_on_humans#Acclimatization), but these aren't changes in body morphology.

So why the difference in children of immigrants?  This is because [diet, nutrition, and disease have quite strong effects on children's growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_height#History_of_human_height). Kids growing up in a healthier environment with more food get bigger, and those are linked to the wealth of the community where you live.

Comment: +1 There is also cause-and-effect relation involved here: immigrants are not a random sample from the population of their original countries. One may argue about whether this translates into educationald and professional achievement, which may affect physical appearance... but teh comparisons between the average immigrants and non-immigrants are likely skewed.